# How does the app know a component is a page

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

Now that the `@Page` decorator had been deprecated, how does the app differentiate between a component that should be used as part of a page and a component that represents a page you can navigate to?

The only difference I see that page components have no `selector` property defined in the `@Component` decorator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A component is considered to be a page if it's pushed to the [navigation controller](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/#page-creation)'s stack.

A `selector` property is optional in an [Angular2 component](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html). You only need it when you want to use the component as an HTML element in the template of another component.

I think the reason `@Page` was deprecated, is that there wasn't so much difference between the two in the first place.

Comment: So there is nothing stopping you adding a component with a `selector` to the navigation stack? no errors?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I would guess that it won't be a problem.