# When should I generate pages and when components in Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I can't completely understand the difference between pages and components in ionic.

As far as I understand `@IonicPage()` enables us to lazy-load the page but what really grinds my gears is that none of the provided examples utilize that (all of them seem to use components as top-level pages).

I am wondering when should I use pages and when components, since they both are easy to generate with the CLI.

Any input and information on the topic is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hope this helps to you:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279191/ionic-3-component-vs-page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page`'s and `component`'s are really the same thing. The concept of a `page` is an Ionic thing, and they are meant to be used as a screen (eq a 'home-page' or 'contact-page') in your app. While a `component` is meant to be used as a part of a `page` (eg custom-contact-card).

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815014/1783706) SO-answer, a `component` is considered a `page` when it gets pushed onto the [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) stack.

The `@IonicPage()` and lazy-loading is quite new and it is possible that the examples your looking at was made before `@IonicPage()` came around. This blog series gives an excellent explanation:
[Part 1](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/)
[Part 2](http://blog.ionic.io/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/)